# How to always load an ember-engines with Ember.JS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-engines

I am currently trying to access my [ember-engines](https://github.com/ember-engines) wherever I am. I want to have the name of each engines, because I want to display every engines in my main application.
The problem here is that I can't find a way to catch there name, because the engines are loaded only if we navigate to a page related to the engines.
This is the services that is normally catching every name of each engines, call it *engines-manager*:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import App from '../app';

/**
 * This service will help us manage every engines that are in our application,
 */

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    availableEngines: [],

    addEngines(engines)
    {
        this.get('availableEngines').push(engines);
        console.log(this.get('availableEngines'));
    }
});
```

And then in every engine, more precisely, in every *anEngines/addon/engine.js* of every engine, I put :

```
import Engine from 'ember-engines/engine';
import loadInitializers from 'ember-load-initializers';
import Resolver from './resolver';
import config from './config/environment';
import Ember from 'ember';

const { modulePrefix } = config;

const Eng = Engine.extend({
    modulePrefix,
    Resolver,
    dependencies: {
        services: [
            'engines-manager'
        ]
    },
    enginesManager: Ember.inject.service('engines-manager'),
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.get('enginesManager').addEngines('nameOfMyEngines');
    }
});

loadInitializers(Eng, modulePrefix);

export default Eng;
```

This method is working if we go on the engines related page, but I dont want to go to every page to load them, so here is my question: **how to always load an ember-engines?**

PS: setting my `lazy-loading` to `true`or `false` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the slack community, we found a workaround. The engine are not means to load if we don't enter it.
So here is a workaround that don't really respond to the answer, but at least you can access to the data present in the engine, like the name, or the services.

### First

You have to create a container in a services, in your app:

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
 fetchEngines()
    {
    let container = Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('application:main').engines; 
    }
});
```

That's it, if you know how to use this data, you have the capacity to fetch the name of the engines for example.

### Secondly

You have now a container, but the data cannot be use like this, container here is not a JSON object for example.

```
let newObject = [];
for (let key in container) {
     if (container.hasOwnProperty(key))
         newObject.push(key);
}
```

Here `newObject` is an array with the name of every engines that are present in your *app.js* in it.
Hope that help some people. I will not accept this response, because this is not what the question ask, but this is a beginning.